# Is it possible to access the sqlserver systable using coldfusion?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

It throw **"The user does not have permission to perform this action"** once fixed the issue means we can access the sql systables using cfquery.

Comment: Yes, providing that the user \ access levels are set with the right permissions

Comment: @SimonPrice you should right up a proper answer to this question.  Then we can upvote and the OP can accept as the correct answer.

Comment: Adding to @SimonPrice's comment: "... and you don't mind your SQL Server being vulnerable to the worst kind of SQL Injection attacks."

Comment: To @AdrianJ.Moreno 's point, I would make sure the account had read only permission on those tables. I would no use a system account.

Comment: Adding to everyone's comment, ask your DBA.

Comment: @DanBracuk and be prepared to hear, "NO!". :)

Comment: I'd just reiterate what the others before me said, but as a DBA, I would ask "Why?" before I likely said "No." Depending on what your reason is for needing that access, there's likely another more secure solution to fit your needs.

Comment: NOTE: I can't really think of a good reason to allow this level of risk into a database. If you don't have a DBA, I'd _STRONGLY_ urge you not to do this. But I will give you some kudos here. If you're seeing "The user does not have permission to perform this action", then you aren't using `sa` as your ColdFusion user. :-)

Comment: Fortunately there is less of that since MS started disabling it, by default :-)